# Is there a good easy protocol for extracting proteins (enzymes) from fungal mycelium?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, microbiology

I quantify the enzyme (polygalacturanase) activity by DNSA method. To determine endo-polygalacturonase activity I'm searching for a good easy enzyme extracting method. Any suggestions for a suitable buffer?

Comment: [Production, Purification, and Characterization of Polygalacturonase from Mucor circinelloides ITCC 6025](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/er/2010/170549/). The authors use a sephacryl S-100 gel filtration column (chromatography), followed by enzyme activity assay and SDS-PAGE.